# Android & java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: android, java.util.concurrent

I want to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue in an android application, have written the code, but now I'm getting an error when the project builds:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2
```

I'm using Eclipse with the lastest version of the ADT plugin.

Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a classpath problem. You shouldn't have to compile it. It's provided in Android API.